# how rotate an image around on oval shape image in css3 animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

am a beginner  in css3 animations.i have one task like,a pen image is rotate around  on oval shape image.as much as i can i tried the following code is used on my task.can you  any one help me please?.

```
 #txtBoxRotateContainer { height: 800px; }
    #txtBoxRotateContainer {
        height: 400px;
        left: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 305px;tive;
        height: 400px;
    }
  div.rocket {
   left: 136px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 316px;
   -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in;


    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 6s infinite;
}



@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);width:250px;left:130px;top:-100px;

  }
  50% { 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);left:80px;top:150xpx;width:360px;
  }
  100% { 
   -webkit-transform:   rotate(-10deg);width:700px;height:500px;top:250px;right:40px;
  }
}

body
{
    line-height:130%;

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent!important;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;">
<img src="../images/page7.jpg" width="778" height="1100" alt="image"/></div>
<div id="txtBoxRotateContainer">
    <div class="rocket"><img src="../images/pencil.png" alt="pencil" /></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is easily done in CSS is to rotate something.
To make it go around in an oval shape, you can deform the place where you are doing the rotation.
And, to make the object that you are rotating keep the aspect ratio, you need to undo the previous transforms.

The HTML:

```
<div class="deform">
<div class="rotate">
<div class="counterrotate">
<div class="inner">A
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.deform  {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(3);
background-color: lightblue;
left: 270px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.rotate {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: circle 10s infinite linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.counterrotate {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
-webkit-animation: ccircle 10s infinite linear;    
}

.inner {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-color: red;
display: block;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0.33);
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes ccircle {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/5w3bE/embedded/result/)

Comment: but i need rotate on vertical oval shape sir.any suggestion?

Comment: the shape is horizontal because there is a scaleX(3). So, if you want to make it vertical, you should find a similar property that does it in the other axis ;-)

Comment: Got the answer thanks sir.deform {
width: 329px;
height: 149px;
-webkit-transform: scaley(1.719);
left: 142px;
position: absolute;
top: 212px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.inner {
-webkit-transform: scaley(0.5);
}