# spin around center with css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

infact i want to make Solar System for an Educational purpose! so a big yellow circle should be in the middle and others should spin around ! but i dont have any idea! just help with spining thing and i will find out other things! i find below code but it just spins around him self!

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidrezabstn/bLqak/

Comment: Don't you mean the _Solar System_? :)

Comment: yes i will do it right nnow

Comment: Maybe [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) helps you.

Comment: I'd recommend you don't do it with CSS. Just use JS and you'll have a easier time of it. Have a look at these - http://paperjs.org/tutorials/

Comment: Milky Way is a galaxy it will be a bit hard to represent with CSS, maybe the Solar System...

Comment: @Joum yeah ! sort of! ;)

Comment: Anyway, the Milky Way is also _kind of_ doable with CSS: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:Milky_Way_Arms.svg it just depends on how much you want to simplify the representation... :)

Comment: @JohnP now im focusing on css! but if its not work i will try js! thank for ur suggestion! :)

Comment: You're in luck - someone's already done the solar system: `http://neography.com/experiment/circles/solarsystem/`

Comment: @kayen thank u so much! i think it will help me alot! make ur comment an answer so i can approve it ;)

Comment: I you wnat to make the orbits eliptical, this answer can be helpful. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17029104/1926369]

Comment: @vals thank u so much it works better than mine! i modifie its new version! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this tutorial/example for the solar system using CSS3:

[CSS3 Solar System](http://neography.com/experiment/circles/solarsystem/)

Answer (score 1):

Using simple CSS will do the trick:

http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/

```
@keyframes rot {
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
               translate(-150px)
               rotate(0deg);
}
to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
               translate(-150px) 
               rotate(-360deg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the simple answer too :D

```
.deform  {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(3);
    background-color: lightblue;
    left: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.rotate {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: circle 10s infinite linear;    
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.counterrotate {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: ccircle 5s infinite linear;    
}

.planet {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius : 50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;

}

@keyframes circle {
    from {transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
    to {transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
}

@keyframes ccircle {
    from {transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
    to {transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hamidrezabstn/fgcPa/3/embedded/result/